# myArraylist.size() cannot find symbol error Java

Tags: java

I made a stack using java generics in order to make a program that calculates a mathematical expression.

Here is the code of the stack:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;   
public class Stack<T> 
    {
    private ArrayList<T> stack;

    public Stack()
    {
        stack = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void push(T item)
    {
        stack.add(item);
        System.out.println(item);
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        T last;
        last = stack.remove((stack.size() - 1));
        System.out.println(last);
        return(last);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {  
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

but when i try to do:

```
 Stack<Integer> number = new Stack<Integer>();
```

in another class which calculates the expression

and then use it to do the following:

```
if(number.size()>=2)
{
    //calculation
}
```

since i have an ArrayList , i get error:canot find symbol in number.size() , can you help me?

Comment: a Stack is not an arraylist, your number variable is of type stack, not List.

Comment: Stack does not contain any member `size`.  I don't understand where your confusion comes from.

Comment: i didnt implemented a size() method in stack , that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Stack<T>
```

doesn't have a `size()` method. You need to impelement one like this

```
public int size() {
    return stack.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `size()` method in your `Stack` class.

```
public class Stack<T> {
    ...

    public int size() {
        return this.stack.size();
    }

    ...
}
```